# unable to maximized chrome browser on remote machine

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can't maximize chrome window using Selenium following are my code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",CONFIG.getProperty("driverPath")+"chromedriver.exe");          
String downloadFilepath = filePath;
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups",0);
//1-Allow, 2-Block, 0-default             
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);           
chromePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
chromePrefs.put("PluginsAllowedForUrls", CONFIG.getProperty("websiteUrl"));

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>()
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");                   
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);            
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);             
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);   
driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

please see attached the [image: screenshot]
Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);            
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);              cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);               cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);    
driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

to this :

```
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);            
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);            
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);             
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);    
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey        After replacing suggest code. it showing compilation error. The method setCapability(String, HashMap<String,Object>) is undefined for the type ChromeOptions.

Comment: There is no setCapability with those two argument.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have you tried this but if not than give it a try:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

or

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768));
```

here 1366 is width and 768 hight of remote machine display.

Hope that helps.

Comment: HI, driver.manage().window().maximize();  and driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768)); and options.addArguments("--start-maximized");   are working on local machine but not in remote machine where my execution triggered.                                   I have integrated my selenium project in CI with TFS plug-in while we triggering execution and run time it will pick the available agent  deploy the code and start execution and here browser is not getting maximized.

Comment: @VpnT Did you ever found a solution for this? Spent the entire day today trying to figure this out, but no luck. I'm also running it remote as part of a CI pipeline. Args --window-size and --window-position work just fine, but --start-maximized does not.

Answer (score 0):

If anything else fails, there is always `JavaScriptExecutor`. You can use

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("window.resizeTo(1366, 768);");
```

where `1366,768` is the dimension or screen size to which you want to maximize.

Comment: Hi, provided solution is not working on local machine as well as remote machine.